# LED Circuit:: First row doesn't light

Tags: led

I made the bellow circuit on breadboard, but my first row of leds ( each directly after the resistors) is not lighting up. What are the possible reasons for it? I tried swapping leds around and again, the LEDs on that position dont work. 
The LEDs are mixxed , 2 of them are from a different set from the rest, all are red, and based on online reading I made the assumption of 1.8 volts. Resistors are 180 Ohms.

[image]

**Update**

The two that are different seem to take 2.2V...

Comment: Perhaps an LED is open or connected backwards (polarity indications are  not necessarily consistent, especially on red LEDs). Try a 2K-ish resistor and test each LED individually before putting the in a circuit or use your multimeter to see if one of the LEDs has more than 1.8V across it.

Comment: Since they are diodes, if one was connected backwards, wouldnt it stop current?

Comment: did yu check if all of them work?

Comment: Just used a multimeter, and the two different ones use 2.2V, the other 7 1.8V the ones that arent working show 0 V

Comment: @Giannis if *all* the ones that are not working show 0V then your connections (or resistor) are bad.

Comment: Since you say it's on a breadboard, I'm going to guess that your schematic is inaccurate. I'm sure the schematic shows what you *intend*, but the breadboard is probably wired in such a way that the first row of LEDs is shorted out.

Comment: And that was the case... I thought that everything would stop working if there was a wrong connection.. I had + and - on the same row for the first 2 led, then the next one on a different row.

Answer (score 2):

**The LED's aren't illuminating because there is only 2mA through each group of 3 LEDs when using 1,800 ohm resistors.**

Observe just *one branch* of your parallel circuit at a time. The voltage drop across each LED is 1.8v.

`3 * 1.8 = 5.4v`

There is going to be a 5.4v drop across a group of 3 LEDs in series.

Seeing the supply is 9v:

`9 - 5.4 = 3.6v` --> 3.6v remain to be dropped across each of the series resistors.

You want 20mA = 0.020A through each series branch. Using [Ohm's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law): V=iR

`3.6 = 0.020R`

`R = 180 ohms`

Perhaps you used 1,800 ohm resistors due to a calculation mistake. Using 1,800 ohm resistors, only 2mA flow through your LEDs, which is not enough to visibly illuminate them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, although I said there resistors are 180 Ohms, I added a space in the question to make this more clear..

Comment: I see your edit to 180 ohms. Do the LEDs illuminate now?

If not, please clearly describe which LEDs have a 1.8v drop and which are 2.2v.

Comment: It turned out to be a short... feeling silly. I took out the two that were 2.2 to make things simpler.

Comment: Hmm. I've definitely seen plenty of light come from an LED with 2 mA. Still, it looks everything is figured out now.

Comment: @AJ7 I thought they were 1800 Ohms too. Even posted a comment and deleted it after I realized, lol.